# How to reuse my kernel density estimation function in R?

Tags: r

I use `density()` to do **KDE**,like

```
 #Rscript#
x <- c(rep(1,3),rep(2,4),rep(3,5))
density(x)
```

Am I suppose to get a probability density function? If so, How do I reuse it to obtain the probability of 1 value e.g. what is the probability of x<=2 **P(x<=2)** under my KDE function?

Tanks for sharing your idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because density() gives you the continous KDE, the probability of an exact value is zero. You can only get some information like P(x <= 1). In your case hist() should be the correct selection.

EDIT:
Please have a look here
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78711/how-to-find-estimate-probability-density-function-from-density-function-in-r

Comment: Thanks. Your idea of P(x <= 1) is what I am talking about, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you have a continuous density, then the thread I linked above will answer your question.

Comment: But using the approx() is an estimation of estimation, do you thing it will work?

Comment: If you have no idea which distribution your sample follows than an approximation is the only solution to determine an approach for both the density and the distribution. If you know the distribution you can test for it with for example the Kolmogorov Smirnov test. And then use the found distribution with the proper estimates for the distribution parameters to determine P(x <= 1).